# why can't I set a particular value in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I am trying to use a value in a for loop as follows:

```
for i = 19:
  dydx[i]=(y[i+1]-y[i])/x
```

I get this error

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

why can't you set variables equal to something?

Comment: Indeed, you can't loop over an integer. You are also using incorrect syntax. What would you expect `for i in 19: print(i)` to do?

Comment: How would `for i = 19` specify a loop?

Comment: So you need to calculate the `dydx` of all numbers from 1 to 19 ?

Comment: no just for i=19.

Comment: Then literally type in `dydx[19]=(y[19+1]-y[19])/x`.

Comment: Or drop the `for` and just write `i = 19`. You don't need a for loop in order to create a variable.

Comment: oh, I didn't realise it was that easy. Thankyou. I have another question- How do I get the print function to print out values corresponding to each element of list such as for x = 0.1, error = ....?

Comment: Comments are not the place to ask new questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't iterate over a single integer, if this will change later to specific values, make it an array of specific value(s):

```
for i in [19]:
    dydx[i]=(y[i+1]-y[i])/x
```

or if you really only want one value of i, then you don't need the loop:

```
i = 19
dydx[i]=(y[i+1]-y[i])/x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [range](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) function (this specific example will iterate from 0 to 19):

```
for i in range(20):
    dydx[i]=(y[i+1]-y[i])/x
```

You can always specify start value like so `range(1, 20)` This will iterate from 1 to 19.

But you can not iterate over int variable. For single value just use:

```
i = 19:
dydx[i]=(y[i+1]-y[i])/x
```

Comment: Seems like this does everything OP does not want. :) Apparently, OP wants `i` to only take the value `19`, while your loop uses all the values from `0` to `18`.

Comment: Well by the quality of the question it's hard to get what OP wants :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking an example with sample values :-

```
dydx = [1,2,3,4,5]

y = [5,6,7,8,8]
x = 10

for i = 3:
    dydx[i]=(y[i+1]-y[i])/x

print(dydx)
```

will yield an error because

> for x = 10:

is not a valid syntax

If you just need to get operations applied on the list, then you may apply something like :-

```
dydx = [1,2,3,4,5]

y = [5,6,7,8,8]
x = 10

i = 3
dydx[i]=(y[i+1]-y[i])/x

print(dydx)
```

This would work!

Comment: thanks! However for my above code, even when I set 19 I get a lot more values than just three corresponding to each element in the list?